# CSS place content with different margins depending the page

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using HTML and CSS to generate a document for printing with wkhtmltopdf. In css I use the @page media and here is my html :

```
<div class="page">
    <div id="content"/>
</div>
```

My content div has a lot of content and spread across pages. I would like that the content has a different margin on the first page, and then margins depending if the page is even or odd.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using a pdf generation class or something? Not enough info to go on I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm using wkhtmltopdf to export my web page into a pdf

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done with `wkhtmltopdf`. Maybe you can try using `pdfjam` on the generated PDF, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31583736/995958